# PHP PDO Fetch returns 0 results when including certain columns

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a connection to the database, calling fetch and getting my results echoed in json; however, when I include certain columns into the select statement... nothing at all comes back.

This is how my code looks:

```
$data = array();
$page = 0;
$perPage = 30;
$offset = $page * $perPage;

$query = "SELECT  wp.ID, 
          REPLACE(wp.post_title, 'Episode - ','') AS header, 
          CASE WHEN img.guid IS NULL THEN meta_img.meta_value ELSE img.guid END AS image_url,
          wp.post_excerpt AS about,  **INCLUDING THIS**
          lessons.meta_value as lessons,  **OR THIS**
          title.meta_value AS detail **OR THIS. BRINGS BACK NO RESULTS**
          FROM wp_posts wp
          INNER JOIN wp_postmeta title on title.post_id = wp.id and title.meta_key = 'academy_title'
          INNER JOIN wp_postmeta lessons on lessons.post_id = wp.id and lessons.meta_key = 'academy_lessons'
          LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta meta_img on meta_img.post_id = wp.id and meta_img.meta_key = 'image'
          LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta meta on meta.post_id = wp.id and meta.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'
          LEFT JOIN wp_posts img on img.id = meta.meta_value
          WHERE wp.post_title LIKE 'Episode%' AND wp.post_status = 'publish' 
          ORDER BY wp.post_date DESC
          LIMIT $offset, $perPage";

        $result = $this->db->query($query);

         while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
                $data[] = $row;
        }    
        echo json_encode($data);
```

I know that my connection works fine because other simpler queries work but for some reason when I include the last 3 columns in the query `(about, lessons, detail)` the result brings nothing back... which makes no sense

I'm kind of new to this so I thought maybe some syntax isn't accepted? But the thing is that it doesn't return results with basic columns not the ones with actual logic...

EDIT:

When doing `SUBSTR(wp.post_excerpt, 1, 4) as about` with the fields and limiting their size... it works. How do I fix this?

Comment: change `lessons.meta_value as lessons,` to `lessons.meta_value as my_lessons,` and try. Also check `var_dump($result);`

Comment: @AlivetoDie I already try to change the aliases incase they were protected keywords and that didn't work. var_dump($result) returns the query... but var_dump($row) in the while loop does return all results...

Comment: `var_dump($row)` having data? then what's the problem?  `echo json_encode($data);`not printing anything?

Comment: @AlivetoDie seems like it yeah

Comment: use `echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($data), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');` and check.Also define `$data  = array();` before `while` loop

Comment: @AlivetoDie nothing. Still only works with top 3 columns and not bottom 3

Answer (score 0):

Check the query on phpAdmin or another and be sure those columns exists and are well written.

UPDATE try

```
 $data = array();      
 while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
                $data[] = $row;
        }
```

UPDATE 2
maybe there is a problem about codification, especial chars, something like that

Comment: The query works perfectly on phpMyAdmin. I'm implementing my PHP API with Slim Framework so copying all of these functioning queries from my least organized API.

Comment: And $row === false ?

Comment: I just did `var_dump($row)` and the records show... what the hell?

Comment: Check connection data, maybe you had to change something and now you are not connecting the database you think you are connecting.

Comment: Did you see my latest reply? I'm connecting to the right database... Printing the rows individually shows the value why don't they get added to $data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143578/discussion-between-fran-cerezo-and-walker).

Comment: Still doesn't work. I was already defining the array just a bit higher. Tried moving it right over the while loop but nothing. Thanks for your help btw